# How to call the oracle function from java. Function returns number

Tags: java

How should I call an Oracle function from Java? The function is supposed to return a number.

```
        CallableStatement cstmt = mJConn.prepareCall("{? = call fnd_request.submit_request( application => 'FND', program => 'JAVACONINSERT', description => 'CSV to DB Insert via Java' ,start_time => sysdate ,sub_request => FALSE, argument1 => '/home/TEST/java/t1.txt')}");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            cstmt.executeUpdate();
            int reqId = cstmt.getInt(1);
        System.out.println(reqId);
```

Comment: what is the problem with your solution?

Comment: Are you trying to call an EBS function or a concurrent program?

Comment: plz give  `int reqId = cstmt.getInt(1);` a try. (case sensitive!)

Comment: `find_request` is a PL/SQL package, yes? `submit_request` is a function in that package, yes? Note that a [PL/SQL] function **is not the same as** a [PL/SQL] procedure.

Comment: Yes its a Package.Function which returns number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
String call = "{?= CALL Proc(?)}";
```

with

```
String call = "{CALL Proc(?, ?)}";
```

The former syntax is for calling a stored function, and the new one is for  a stored procedure.

You can also to swap the order of the bind parameters :

```
cs.setString(1, "String");
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
```